# Buttons Disappear when I click after moving iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I move my buttons upon rotation to landscape, the move properly but when I click, they all disappear. Does anyone know why?

```
UIButton *recordingButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
CGRect frame1 = [recordingButton frame];
frame1.origin.x += 255;
frame1.origin.y -= 250;// change the location
[recordingButton setFrame:frame1];

UIButton *streamingButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:2];
CGRect frame2 = [streamingButton frame];
frame2.origin.x += 255;
frame2.origin.y -= 250;// change the location
[streamingButton setFrame:frame2];

UIButton *uploadButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:3];
CGRect frame3 = [uploadButton frame];
frame3.origin.x += 255;
frame3.origin.y -= 250;// change the location
[uploadButton setFrame:frame3];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using auto layout in your storyboard. You can't go changing the `frame` of a view positioned using auto layout constraints; it is the *constraints* that position it. Use constraints (preferably the constraints in the storyboard) to do what you are doing here in code.